# Which act should be chosen according to the principle of maximizing expected monetary value ( EVM )?

Tags: game-theory, decision-theory

Assume that the decision maker's utility `u` of money is linear.

Consider

```
-  1/2  1/4  1/4
a1 $49  $24  $25
a2 $36  $100 $0
a3 $81  $0   $0
```

according to the principle of maximizing expected money value, which should be chosen?

Context:  I am going through "An Introduction to Decision Theory" by Martin Peterson and the book says `a2` which I cannot arrive at.  Here is my work:

`a1 = 1/2 x 49 + 1/4 x 25 + 1/4 x 25 = 49.5`

`a2 = 1/2 x 36 + 1/4 x 100 + 1/4 x 0 = 43`

`a3 = 1/2 x 81 + 1/4 x 0 + 1/4 x 0 = 40.5`

I come up with `a1`.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your reasoning is fine; check your arithmetic.

Comment: a1 is worth 36.75.

Comment: ah, thanks @TheoreticalEconomist and Misha .  if i had 1.1 dollars for every time i knew what to do and screwed up the basic math I would have 10.6 dollars